How much do your undergraduate and graduate GPAs matter when applying for a faculty position?
I’m looking for a job in academia and was a little concerned about my undergraduate GPA (Grade Point Average) (around 3.0) from a good school.
I had masters and Ph.D. GPA around 4.0 from good schools and a list of decent publications in good journals. It has been more than 10 years since I got my undergraduate GPA but it just suddenly came to my mind while preparing CV and application.

Your recent publication record is far more important than your grades from way back.  Rather a productive scientist who didn't excel at written exams than someone who can perfectly ace exams but lacks the creativity to produce great science.
Don't worry about it.  Good luck on your job search.

Indeed, it's unlikely they'll even LOOK at your grades, let alone care about them.

Thank you for the assurance. It helps a lot.

Really the only people that will care about undergraduate GPAs are the hiring manager for someone's first job after getting their bachelor's, and the application committees for grad schools. Once you've graduated from grad school, basically no one will care about, or even ask for, undergraduate GPAs. And once you have your first job out of grad school, almost no one will care about your grad school GPA, either. As gerrit said, by that point you have much better metrics for success to be judged on than how well you did exams and homework. Unless explicitly asked, you can pretty much stop including anything about GPAs/coursework on your resumes/CVs after that first job experience out of grad school.
